# Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm learning to write a Google extension. I tried Google Charts example and encountered a bug:

`Refused to load the script '`[`https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js`](https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js)`' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.`

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the manifest.json I use

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "description": "description",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon.png",
    "32": "icon.png",
    "48": "icon.png",
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "action": {
      "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "background": {
      "service_worker": "./scripts/background.js",
      "type": "module"
  },
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.0.1"
}
```

I've tried some solutions about Content Security Policy, but none of them works for me.

Comment: The `Content-Security-Policy` header of your document should include `script-src 'self' *.gstatic.com` to allow the script to be loaded.

Comment: You cannot load external scripts in a MV3 extension. Download the `loader.js` script and include it in your extension with a script tag. Also, move your inline script into a separate file and load it with a `<script src="yourscript.js"></script>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": [
      "index.html"
    ]
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' https://www.gstatic.com"
  }
}
```

[image]